# I need a way to return out of a function without having to return the "return type"

Tags: c++, return

I have a function that allocates memory and then returns the pointer to that memory address. I'm allocating an array of char, the argument that they pass into the function will be the array size. Now the problem is that if they pass `0` as the argument for the size to dynamically allocate, then I want to exit/return out of that function, but the function itself returns a `char *` so I am not able to do something like `return -1;`, how would I go around this, while at the same time keeping the function and doing logic to allocate the memory in there? Is there a way?

```
char *alloate_memory(int x) { // This will assume you are allocating memory for a C-style string
    if (x == 0)
        return ;
    char *mem{ new char[x] };
    return mem;
}
```

Comment: Maybe `return nullptr;` or throw an exception.

Comment: Why the `mem` variable? `return new char[x];` is perfectly legal code.

Comment: Note that it's valid to have a zero size dynamic allocation. So there's really no need to check for `x == 0`, because it's a valid value of `x`. It is however invalid to use negative numbers, so you should check for that instead. Or better yet, use an unsigned type like `std::size_t`.

Comment: You might also want to consider what you should do if `x` is less than zero.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude if I x were to be 0 would new char[x] return nullptr?

Comment: @john I actually have some more logic in mind to have there, but I didn't add it as I was trying to figure out a way to go around this, sorry for not adding more context.

Comment: @Krapnix It's implementation defined. It could bery well return a valid pointer, but one you can't actually dereference. What is the reson you use plain pointers to char? If this is for a string why don't you use `std::string`? If it's for general small-value integers, then `std::vector<char>` (but remember that it's implementation defined if `char` is `signed` or `unsigned`, better use `std::uint8_t` or `std::int8_t` or possible `std::byte`)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I was trying to do it with a C-style string. I have another function which takes a std::string and I wanted to have a go at using a C-style string to pass to that function, and so I changed that other function to accept a `char *` instead.

Comment: @Krapnix You do know that `std::string` has `c_str()` and `data()` methods for getting a `char*` pointer, don't you?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Nope I wasn't aware of that :p, but it still wouldn't have mattered for me, I just wanted to do it all myself, like I have shown above, it is really the only way you get to learn different ways (that may or may not be best practises in c++/modern c++) to do things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct way to signal that a pointer doesn't point to valid memory is with a `nullptr`. So your `return` statement in the case that the memory allocation fails would simply be:

```
return nullptr;
```

Of course, the caller of the function needs to make sure that the returned pointer is not `nullptr` before they try to dereference it.

Answer (score 6):

The canonically correct way to do this given that the input parameter must be an `int` is either:

```
char *alloate_memory(int x) { // This will assume you are allocating memory for a C-style string
    if (x <= 0)
        throw std::bad_alloc();

    return new char[x];
}
```

or

```
char *alloate_memory(int x) { // This will assume you are allocating memory for a C-style string
    if (x <= 0)
        return nullptr;

    return new(std::nothrow) char[x];
}
```

Depending on if you want it to throw an exception or return nullptr on error. I recommend you pick one and not mix them for consistency

Answer (score 5):

The common practice would be to return `nullptr`:

```cpp
char *alloate_memory(int x) { // This will assume you are allocating memory for a C-style string
    if (x == 0)
        return nullptr; // here!
    char *mem{ new char[x] };
    return mem;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The general consensus is to return `NULL` in C or `nullptr` in C++. Its value is 0 and can be cast to an address (which itself is actually an integer).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```cpp
char *alloate_memory(int x) { // This will assume you are allocating memory for a C-style string
    char *mem{ new char[x] };
    return mem;
}
```

You will be allocating memory for a zero length char.
Alternatively or If it doesn't work : Throw an error:

```cpp
char *alloate_memory(int x) { // This will assume you are allocating memory for a C-style string
    if (x <= 0)
        throw std::length_error("Memory size too small (cannot be 0 or smaller)");
    char *mem{ new char[x] };
    return mem;
}
```

or return a nullptr:

```cpp
char *alloate_memory(int x) { // This will assume you are allocating memory for a C-style string
    if (x == 0)
        return nullptr;
    char *mem{ new char[x] };
    return mem;
}
```